# Как заставить работать .htaccess в Laravel?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, laravel

Привет.

Я хочу вынести админку проекта в отдельную папку. Она будет на laravel.

Если сайт имеет такую структуру:

site.ru/admin(папка)/(Тут Laravel файлы)
То .htaccess в папке admin не работает.

Если такую:
site.ru/(Тут Laravel файлы) - работает.

Можете подсказать .htaccess который решит проблему для первого случая?

сам .htaccess самый дефолтный,для удаление public из url.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

То есть,адресс : site.ru/admin/public/home, мне нужно сократить до:
site.ru/admin/home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кто-то не умеет нормально в гугл и стаковерфлов,тогда,для них ответик:

Переименуйте server.php в index.php, и возьмите .htaccess из public папки. Это все.

Проблема со стилями,решается так:

Обновите метод в : /Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php/asset()

```
 public function asset($path, $secure = null)
  {
   if ($this->isValidUrl($path)) return $path;
   $root = $this->getRootUrl($this->getScheme($secure));
   return $this->removeIndex($root).'/public/'.trim($path, '/');
  }
```

Источник: [Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/110587)

Comment: @DenisBubnov Теперь не работают стили. Не подскажешь как это можно пофиксить?

Если URL: site.ru/admin - {{ asset() }} не работает.
Если URL: site.ru/admin/public - {{ asset() }} работает. 

Стили подключается только по прямому указанному пути с public ..

Comment: @DenisBubnov, уже ничего. ложная тревога,спасибо.

Comment: В любом случае советую внести правку в ответ. Ответ должен содержать в себе информацию только с решением проблемы, а не с тем, кто чем не умеет пользоваться. Текст на английском либо переведите, либо уберите вовсе.